# mongo $text {$search: "something"}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to make searching in mongo using a part of the word that stored in the document

```js
getCitiesWithQuery(reqQuery) {
    let query = {$text: {$search: reqQuery}};
    return db.collection('cities').find(query).toArray();
}
```

But I`ve got this error:

```
MongoError: text index required for $text query
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You need to look at the [$text documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#examples), the error clearly says it requires `text` index on specific fields. at least try to search that error in google, you will get some idea what you missed.

Comment: getCitiesWithQuery(reqQuery) {
        db.collection('cities').createIndex({ "name": "text"});
        let query = {$text: {$search: reqQuery}, caseSensitive: false};
        return db.collection('cities').find(query).toArray();
    }

Comment: I did exactly as they exposed in docs but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to create text index on that collection first.
This example code below indexes every field that contains string data for each document in the collection

```
db.cities.createIndex(
   { "$**": "text" }
 )
```

Comment: ```
getCitiesWithQuery(reqQuery) {
        db.collection('cities').createIndex({ "name": "text"});
        let query = {$text: {$search: reqQuery}, caseSensitive: false};
        return db.collection('cities').find(query).toArray();
    }

Comment: It doesn`t do what I expect(((

Comment: I think you need to create index outside of your query function, not while executing the query

Comment: No, It created the index called text but It doesnt do what I expected

Comment: I need to find a way of searching in the field with a part of a word

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $text looks for words only. If you're using MongoDB Atlas, you can make use of [Atlas Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/), which allows for partial searching (and fuzzy matching and other things).